# mysqli_stmt_affected_rows doesn't work for update prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this code

```
$SQL = "UPDATE cart SET a = ? WHERE b = ? AND c = ?";
            
            if($stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($conn, $SQL )){
                        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, "iii", $a1, $b1, $c1);
                        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
                       
                if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)){
                    echo "updated";
                    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt2);
                }
                else
                    echo "nope";
            }
```

I was figuring out why above code never work. I have debug every way that I know.

Lastly I delete the if condition. Somehow, it is working. Tried to browse on the internet to figure out what is the cause but did not find any. Can somebody please explain to me why does it happen so?

Answer (score 5):

You should be using

```
mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt2);
```

> **mysqli_stmt::$affected_rows -- mysqli_stmt_affected_rows** — Returns the total number of rows changed, deleted, or inserted by the last executed statement

Instead of

```
mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
```

which is for plain query executions.

**[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php)**

**Edit**

I just noticed that your question title mentions the *right* function name, and your code uses the *wrong* one.

Comment: This shouldn't really make any difference. The `affected_rows` value is copied to the `mysqli` object from prepared statement so using either function you will get the correct result.